# Embed server tags inside client side HTML\JS scripts without template engines

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, client-server, mean

I would like to do the following inside a client side java script from a file hosted using node and express

```
var rootURL = <%= "someurlfromserverconfig" %>;
```

I simply host a web directory from my node app. I have no need for template engines. I just want to access some simple server properties for examples an API URL. ASP and PHP have a similar feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple things as that are easy to handle with `toString` and `replace`:

```
var url = 'example.com'
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(500)
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.send(data.toString().replace('<%= "someurlfromserverconfig" %>', '"' + url + '"'))
  })
})
```

This would yield: `var rootUrl = "example.com";`

For caching purposes you might want to read the file into memory and run your `replace` beforehand instead of on each request, but that's your choice.

To elaborate on the workflow; `fs.readFile` returns a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) that you can run `toString()` on which then allows you to run `replace()`.

Comment: Svenskunganka thank you for your time but with this I would have to handle every request. It is somewhat similar to a template engine. I was just hoping there was something similar to PHP or ASP

Comment: PHP and ASP handles this on *every request* as well. Node.js or Express doesn't have built-in templating like PHP or ASP does, you are free to choose whatever templating engine you want that is available. There's a huge difference in how Node.js and PHP for example works. PHP was built primarily for Web Development while Node.js is a general scripting platform similar to Ruby, Python or Golang. You can build any type of applications with Node, CLI applications for example.

Comment: And to be honest, if you want the capabilities of PHP or ASP you should use PHP or ASP, there's nothing wrong with those languages. If you want to learn Node, you're going to have to choose a templating engine to do this kind of stuff as Node.js doesn't have those kind of capabilities built-in. I recommend [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) but there are many others you can choose between.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intent on not having to process a template on every request, and if the data you want to include are not going to change on the fly, you might consider [ES6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). You could host your code in a file like this:

```
'use strict';

const config = require('./server-config');

module.exports = `
var rootURL = "${config.rootURL}";

// ...
`;
```

And then you would require the file in whatever file is handling the routing. The template will only be processed once, even if it is required by multiple files.

Alternatively, you could just use a lightweight template engine, render it once, and then serve it whenever it is requested. If you want to use exactly that format, I would recommend [EJS](http://ejs.co/).

```
'use strict';

const ejs = require('ejs');
const config = require('./server-config');

let template = fs.readFileSync('./some-template.js', 'utf8');
let rendered = ejs.render(template, config);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(rendered);
});
```

If the data you are sending are constantly changing, you will have to render the template every time. Even ASP and PHP have to do that under the hood.